# AWS SQS sender setting a time for message to be avilable for the consumer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have seen an option called **visibility timeout** in AWS SQS which sets a time for other consumers to ignore the message which is being processed by one.
Is there an option to set a time before the message actually becomes available for consumers to use it, may be set while message actually is inserted into Queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an option called **Amazon SQS Message Timers**
Amazon SQS message timers allow you to specify an initial invisibility period for a message that you add to a queue. For example, if you **send a message with the DelaySeconds parameter** set to 45, the message isn't visible to consumers for the first 45 seconds during which the message stays in the queue.
The default value for DelaySeconds is 0.

To set a delay period that applies to all messages in a queue, use delay queues. A message timer setting for an individual message **overrides any DelaySeconds value that applies to the entire delay queue**.

For more info on SQS check  [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dg.pdf)  detailed PDF by AWS

Answer (score 2):

There is such an option, but it is a queue-level option, not a message-level option:

> You can use the `CreateQueue` action to create a delay queue by setting the `DelaySeconds` attribute to any value between 0 and 900 (15 minutes). You can also change an existing queue into a delay queue using the `SetQueueAttributes` action to set the queue's `DelaySeconds` attribute
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html

When the value is nonzero, all messages are delayed by the specified number of seconds before they are initially visible to any consumer.

Comment: Actually, need the option at message level.Found another option called "message-timer" Yet to try it out. Will update once done

Comment: @JithPS you are right.  You found the correct answer.  Please post it as an answer here and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

When you are processing the message, you can actually use ChangeMessageVisibility() . This allows you to change the timeout period while holding the message either up or down. For example, if you KNOW that your message failed the first time, you can set it to 0 and it will put it back on the queue.  If you wanted a specifically longer timeout, you could check for that type of message and set it to 10 minutes for example.